# several ggplot2 plots on top on an image

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I have this nice custom plot function based on ggplot2

What I would now like to do, is to place several plots drawn with this 
function on top of a background image (loaded in as a png).

I do not want to place the plots on a regular grid, but rather
at select locations on the image.

(An example of such a plot is can be seen on 
http://www.climatechange2013.org/images/figures/WGI_AR5_Fig10-21.jpg)

It seems to me that I will need to have each of my plots drawn within a distinct environment, and a method for placing these environments at select coordinates on the image.

Can anyone direct me to the right packages/tutorial/blogs/etc that
could be of use for this?

Sincerely,
Halldór

Comment: Overly general questions like this are considered off-topic in SO, especially so since it asks for package recs and tutorials. Perhaps the rules would be less strict on one of the other stackexchange venues. Why not review the terms at the GIS forum?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Embedded Plots via ggplot:
http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/embedded-plots.pdf
and `ggsubplot`-Packages.

Or do it "by hand" via-`ggplot2::annotation_raster`.
Taking this Image: http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/16/12/34/squares-35798_640.png

```
require(ggplot2)
require(png)
library(RCurl)
myurl <- "http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/16/12/34/squares-35798_640.png"
mypng <-  readPNG(getURLContent(myurl))

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  annotation_raster(mypng, xmin=min(df$x), xmax = max(df$x), ymin=min(df$y), ymax=max(df$y)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Now you can add whatever layer `geom_...` you want. Probably you need to modify `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` accordingly.

[image]

Comment: if I'm not mistaken that's images over a plot, not plots over an image

Comment: Thank you. My problem could probably be solved via embedded plots. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @baptiste it depends on the order of ggplot-commands (i.e. the order of adding layers). If you call `geom_point` before `annotation_raster`, the image is plotted above the points, else points above image.

Answer (score 1):

Using an exemplary [image](http://images.wikia.com/uncyclopedia/images/archive/4/4a/20110525012805!!0Russia-map.png) here one approach:

```
library(png)
ima <- readPNG("C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/rus.png")
png <- "C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/rus.png"
ima <- readPNG(png)
library(ggplot2)

tm <- theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = "black"), # or theme_blank()
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)
)

plot.new()
lim <- par()
rasterImage(ima, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])

library(grid)
vp <- viewport(.25, 0.65, width =.3, height = .3)
pl <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_histogram() + tm
print(pl, vp = vp)

pl2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_line() + tm
vp2 <- viewport(.75, 0.65, width =.3, height = .3)
print(pl2, vp = vp2)

pl3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_line() + tm
vp3 <- viewport(.5, 0.4, width =.3, height = .3)
print(pl3, vp = vp3)
```

[image]

Comment: or `annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(p))`

Comment: Thank you, This seems to be it!

Comment: it would probably make more sense to use `grid.raster` instead of `rasterImage`; mixing base and grid graphics is generally best avoided.