# controlling plot size and position on top of an imported image

Tags: r, image, plot

I would like make a plot on top of an image where I can adjust the size of the plot on top of the image, if possible. Ideally the image should be larger then the plot...
Here is some example code to start from:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(jpeg)
library(scales)
library(grid)

#picture from internet
myurl <- "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg"
z <- tempfile()
download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")
pic <- readJPEG(z)
file.remove(z) # cleanup

x <- sample(1:10, replace=T, 10)
y <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", "j")

df <- data.frame(y,x)

p <-ggplot(df, aes(y, x, fill=y)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(pic, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 
                    -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="red",width=0.8, alpha=0.75 )+
  #geom_text(aes(label=data2$Attributes), vjust=1.5,colour="black")
  ggtitle("Something")+  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = "yyy", x = "xxx") + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16))+ theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text( size = 14)) + theme(legend.title = element_text( size = 16))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white", linetype = "dotted"))
p
```

this results in a picture looking like:

[image]

Ideally I would like to place the barplot with a smaller size for example in the top right corner or anywhere I choose to with a scalable size..

Any ideas?

Comment: One possibility would be to plot your image first. Them create a viewport with a smaller size on top of it and plot your graph in it.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963671/several-ggplot2-plots-on-top-on-an-image)

Comment: @RHA, great exactly what I was looking for, thanks